# Fragments stacking on each other

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem with fragments. In my xml file I have a fragment already set there, I want with the click of a button replace it with another fragment. So with my code I can replace the fragment with the one that I want on the click of the button, but the first fragment wont disappear, so I can still see it under my second fragment, the code it's this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      button = findViewById(R.id.button);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

              FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
              fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,new BlankFragment2());
              fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
          }
      });
    }    
}
```

Comment: You cannot remove/replace `Fragment`s defined in your layout with a `<fragment>` element. The correct solution is to replace that `<fragment>` with a `<FrameLayout>`, and load that `Fragment` into it yourself in code, at startup. The subsequent `replace()` calls will then work as expected. The answer you've accepted is a hacky workaround, at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a background color of the root layout of the second fragment and put clickable and focusable true in xml file. It will make disappear of the first fragment and also disable the clicks of first fragment when showing another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `addToBackStack(null)`.

That stores the Fragment and keeps it attached so that calling `popBackStack()` will remove the top Fragment and replace it with the previous.

Comment: i did delete it and of course i did put the commit () after the replace, but still wont disappear the first fragment :S

Comment: the weird thing is that the text'color of the fragments, cause there is a text view in the layout it's different! when there is only the first fragment it's black! then when i replace it with the second fragment, the second one is black! but the first turn to a light  grey!

Answer (score 0):

correctly implementing addToBackStack will help in this case and many other 
addToBackStack takes an argument which is called task record TAG , To perform a transaction later on , you can use this tag to remove back stack up to a point

For more understanding read 
https://medium.com/@bherbst/managing-the-fragment-back-stack-373e87e4ff62

Comment: It's not a tag, it's a name.